# Android for loop not working properly

Tags: android, for-loop

I'm trying to develop an android application where images can be set invisible one by one each 3 seconds.I tired doing it using following code.

```
final ImageView[] i = new ImageView[6];
public int l=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cs_game_two);


    i[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    i[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    i[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    i[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    i[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    i[5] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);

    image_set();

}

    public void image_set()
{
    for( l=0; l<6; l++){

        i[l].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                i[l].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

In this im getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.When i change for loop condition to `l<5` only i[5] image will be set invisible.I can't seem to understand how to solve this please help.

Comment: The parameter l value does not contain the value you believe.
You have a global l. and a private l in the function image_set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that implements Runnable and pass the ImageView as constructor parameter. Currently the value can change and really a mess can happen.

Example:

```
private class MyRun implements Runnable {
private ImageView iv;

public MyRun(ImageView v){
  iv = v;
}

@Override
public void run() {
   iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

}
```

Comment: I would give each Runnable a reference to `ImageView` and get rid of all the globals

Comment: Can u please give a example?